# Clear stack frame on return (C)

Tags: c, clang

Is there some clever way to force the runtime system to clear a stack frame on a return from a function? I'm looking for a compiler flag or some sort of interesting hack.

We are trying to create a "chaos build" for students that will have bad behavior and expose more bugs to students. I know that AddressSanitizer and valgrind can detect things like this, but I would really like to be able to demonstrate errors resulting from this type of bad code. For example:

```
int *foo() {
  int a = 10;
  return &a;
}

int bar() {
  int * a = foo();
  printf("%d\n", *a); // I would like to guarantee that this line doesn't print 10
}
```

Comment: "Clear" as in, what, zero the memory?

Comment: Your "chaos build" implies undefined behaviour (as does your example), thus there is no way to write such code which also behaves predictably. By definition. How do you feel about using assembly instead?

Comment: That code wouldn't print 10 anyway.... it would try to print the ***pointer*** `a`, which probably has a value like `123947120`.   Perhaps you meant `printf("%d\n", *a); // Value stored at A`

Comment: Sanitize by immediately calling another function that defines an array full of zeros?

Comment: I think what you want is to hook function invocation to allocate, and switch to, a brand new stack. On return, you want to free that stack and mark the memory it formerly occupied inaccessible.

Comment: yeah it would print the pointer, let me fix that

Comment: by clear I mean zero. And yes, I'm looking to force the undefined behavior to create errors. On its own, this code will almost always work.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you nailed it. Is there any good way to do this in C?

Comment: Don't know that it can be done portably, in fact I am pretty sure it can't. But specific compilers may provide "hooks" into the prolog/epilog code. For example VC has the option to call a user defined `_pexit` at the end of every function [/GH (Enable _pexit Hook Function)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc11y76y.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried "volatile" as keyword for `int * a = foo()` and `int a`? That would force the compiler not to optimize these variables. You could also try it maybe with the `-O0` compiler flag.

Comment: gcc has the `-finstrument-functions` option to hook in code just after function entry and just before function exit. I couldn't find a reference for the same option in clang but a search does bring up results of others using that option with clang. So that might work for you.

Comment: Why not just tell them that it's undefined behavior and what that means?

Comment: When compiling with optimizations, this code already gives me a garbage value with clang and a segfault with gcc: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d892700467ba1bd0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may probably do an intermediate function callout so, that the stack frame from the function foo is overwriten. Something like in the example below. In this case the result returned by foo() will be overwritten, and thus the output won't be 10.

```
5 int *foo()
6 {
7   int a = 10;
8   return &a;
9 }
10
11 int f()
12 {
13     int x = 5;
14
15     return x;
16 }
17
18 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
19 {
20     int * a = foo();
21
22     f();
23
24     printf("%d\n", *a);
25
26     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
27 }
```